# How to remove a tub insert

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, demolition, tub

We're looking at the effort and time for a bathroom renovation, and the biggest item on the list is replacing an old fiberglass tub insert/surround with a standing shower insert/surround.

Looking at the new inserts, I see that installation involves screwing the base and surrounds directly to exposed studs...so I'm *guessing* that's how the old tub is installed now.

The question is, what's the correct way to go about removing the old tub? I see no visible place to remove screws (clean sheet rock up to the tub and surround). Is it bust a bunch of holes and hope for the best? Is there a correct way of doing this that minimizes a.) damage to repair later and b.) time involved for the whole affair?

Comment: [Sledgehammer](http://www.antiqueradios.com/gallery/d/126761-1/sledgehammer.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently took apart the bathroom in my basement. It was a steel tub and I had to bust up the tiles around it to take the screws out, then bust a hole in the other side of the wall to disconnect the plumbing. If you don't need to save it, take your anger out on it. Just be careful not to smash it near the plumbing and be careful to smash it only where it's not directly contacting a stud. If you hit it wrong, you could damage the other side of the wall. I would get everything around it down to bare studs before trying to remove it, just to be safe so you can see what you're doing.

Also, some bath tubs have their base set in thinset. If that's the case, you'll probably need to cut a section of floor board out and replace it.